# What does "a final step for a period to be agreed upon" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Ran into this:

> This comprehensive solution would build on these initial measures and result in **a final step for a period to be agreed upon** and the resolution of concerns.

I think the above equals this:

> This comprehensive solution would build on these initial measures and would result in a final step for a period which is to be agreed upon and would result in the resolution of concerns.

I have a question about the noun phrase **a final step for a period to be agreed upon**. What does it mean? Could somebody rephrase it? What does *for a period* mean here?
Could someone kindly say what the text is saying?

Comment: I agree with your interpretation.

Comment: What do you think *a final step for a period which is to be agreed upon* mean?

Comment: I would think that there are several steps in the context (a negotiation?), and the result of the "comprehensive solution" would be a "final step" that will be agreed upon (by whoever involved in the context). Without more context, I have to assume that the desired solution and measures must include the period of the agreement(s?); and that's the "period to be agreed upon".

Comment: To put it simply, let's assume that A and B want to reach some agreement. The agreement seems to be complex enough. It has many concerns,
and the process to reach the agreement is also complex (let's call it a "negotiation"). The result of the negotiation (the "agreement") seems to include the "resolution"
along with a "period" (length of time) that such the resolution will be put to use. ...

Comment: ... The negotiation seems to require many steps before complete. Up to this point, the negotiation has reached initial measures. Both A and B are trying to make a comprehensive solution based on these initial measures. The solution would result in such the "resolution" along with the "period" to be agreed upon.

Comment: Another note, I parsed it as: *This comprehensive solution would build on these initial measures and result in [a final step for [a period to be agreed upon] and [the resolution of concerns]].*

Comment: context: http://edition.cnn.com/2013/11/24/world/meast/iran-deal-text/index.html

Comment: Then I stand by my interpretation above.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot understand your interpretation completely:( Can you say what you meant in a simpler way?

Comment: Let consider the sentence: *[This comprehensive solution] would [build on these initial measures] and [result in [a final step for [a period to be agreed upon] and [the resolution of concerns]]].* It's about "the comprehensive solution". This solution would build on the earlier mentioned "initial measures" and would result in "a final step". This final step is for two things: "a period" (to be agreed upon) and "the resolution" (of concerns).

Comment: According to the source, here is part of "elements of a first step": *"The first step would be time-bound, with a duration of 6 months, and renewable by mutual consent, during which all parties will work to maintain a constructive atmosphere for negotiations in good faith."*

Comment: @DamkerngT. I think you've got the makings of an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"a final step for a period to be agreed upon" is rather clumsily written.

The important issue here is about the meaning of "[for](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/for)", which is

> used as a function word to indicate purpose
>
> used as a function word to indicate an intended goal
>
> used as a function word to indicate the object or recipient of a
> perception, desire, or activity

So the solution will result in a final step that will allow for a period of time to be agreed upon

It is also possible that "for" is used here

> as a function word to indicate duration of time or extent of space

ie,  The solution will result in a final step that will last for a period of time that will be agreed upon

The sentence could be more clearly written as either

> This comprehensive solution would build on these initial measures and
> result in a final step [that would allow] for a period [of time] to be
> agreed upon and [would also result in (*or* would also allow for)] the resolution of concerns.

or

> This comprehensive solution would build on these initial measures and
> result in a final step [that would last] for a period [of time, which
> is] to be agreed upon and [would also result in] the resolution of concerns.

or could be entirely rephrased [in a way that would allow] for simplicity and greater clarity.

Answer (score 5):

Let consider the sentence:

> [This comprehensive solution] would [build on these initial measures] and [result in [a final step for [a period to be agreed upon] and [the resolution of concerns]]].

- It's about a ***"comprehensive solution"***.
- This solution would do two things: it would build on the earlier mentioned ***"initial measures"***, and it and would result in ***"a final step"***.
- According to the sentence, this "final step" is for two things: ***"a period"*** *(to be agreed upon)* and ***"the resolution"*** *(of concerns)*.

The phrase ***"a period to be agreed upon"*** means a duration (of time) that all parties in the negotiation would agree upon. In our case, the negotiation is the nuclear deal between Iran and six world powers.

According to the [source](http://edition.cnn.com/2013/11/24/world/meast/iran-deal-text/index.html), here is part of "elements of a first step":

> The first step would be time-bound, with a duration of 6 months, and renewable by mutual consent, during which all parties will work to maintain a constructive atmosphere for negotiations in good faith.

Comment: Excuse me:( I understand most of what you said but again I do not get what "result in a final step for a period to be agreed upon"? Does it say that this final step should be achieved in a specific period of time?I mean "these negotiations should reach the goal in the agreed period"?

Comment: I'm glad that you asked. Please don't hesitate to ask if the answer wasn't clear enough for you. About our final step. The period means the "duration" that the agreement is effective once it's put to use. From the news report, *The first step would be time-bound, with a duration of 6 months, and renewable by mutual consent, ...* This means that once the agreement is put to use (the start date), **all parties must do whatever the agreement states for 6 months, counted from the start date**. This period is also "renewable by mutual consent", according to the report.

Comment: Thank you. Well I Don't think this sentence is talking about this. It is talking about the final step which is to be reached after these initial steps during the next 6 months after the starting date. If it were "This comprehensive solution would build on these initial measures for a period to be agreed upon and result in a final step that resolves the concerns.", it was OK but now I do not get the meaning completely! why has *for a period to be agreed on* been put where it is?

Comment: If I understand the original sentence correctly, "This comprehensive solution would build on these initial measures for a period to be agreed upon and result in a final step that resolves the concerns." would have a different meaning from the original sentence. If we state it that way, it would sound like "build X within [a period that is not yet defined]". The original is clearer, it says "the final step will be enforced for [a period that is to be defined]".

Comment: Also note that the final step is not finalized yet. As stated by the report, *With respect to the final step and any steps in between, the standard principle that ˈnothing is agreed until everything is agreedˈ applies.ˈ* However, they aim to reach such agreement within one year (which is a different thing from the "period to be agreed upon" in our sentence), i.e. *The final step of a comprehensive solution, which the parties aim to conclude negotiating and commence implementing no more than one year after the adoption of this document, would ...*

Comment: Truly thx pal. I have to work more on this text and come back to this phrase again. Now I feel a bit confused.